# Get values of array of unions

Tags: typescript

Given is the following interface:

```
export interface ContainsArrayOfUnions {
  unionProp: Array<"TRUE" | "FALSE" | "MAYBE">;
}
```

Now I want to write a function with two parameters, first an array type of unionProp, the second one of the union values:

```
checkValue(param1: ContainsArrayOfUnions["unionProp"], param2: ???) {
  return param1.includes(param2);
}
```

**My question**

How do I create a type of the values of the union array Array<"TRUE" | "FALSE" | "MAYBE">?

**EDIT** Adding tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "pretty": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noStrictGenericChecks": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./src/types"
    ],
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "esnext",
      "esnext.array",
      "dom.iterable"
    ],
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "noErrorTruncation": true,
    "paths": {
      "@coreStyles/*": ["./src/assets/styles/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest

```
type ArrayType = "TRUE" | "FALSE" | "MAYBE";

export interface ContainsArrayOfUnions {
  unionProp: ArrayType[]
}

checkValue(param1: ContainsArrayOfUnions["unionProp"], param2: ArrayType) {
  return param1.includes(param2);
}
```

or using the code you already have:

```
checkValue(param1: ContainsArrayOfUnions["unionProp"], param2: "TRUE" | "FALSE" | "MAYBE") {
  return param1.includes(param2);
}
```

UPDATE:
(a bit hacky, but works)

```
checkValue<T extends ContainsArrayOfUnions["unionProp"][0]>(param1: ContainsArrayOfUnions["unionProp"], param2: T) {
  return param1.includes(param2);
}
```

Comment: Yes, sure I could define the type myself. In my real life scenario the type is more complex and dynamic (it is generated from a changing swagger.json).

Comment: Nice idea, but does not work because of 1. `Property '0' does not exist on type ("TRUE" | "FALSE" | "MAYBE")[]` and 2. T is not assignable to type "MAYBE".

Comment: that is strange. what version of typescript are you using? you can as well try <T extends ContainsArrayOfUnions["unionProp"][number]>, but don't think so since [0] doesn't work

Comment: I am using typescript@3.5.3. Could this be related to my tsconfig.json? I added my config to my post.